# Is it possible to build a Inno Setup script line from variables

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to build a script line using a variable and some conditions (have executable that requires different switches depending on what is checked on a custom page.  Possibly something like this:

```
var
linecommand : string;
function FileParams();
  begin
    if check1 then linecommand := linecommand+' conditionone' end;
    if check2 then linecommand := linecommand+' conditiontwo' end;
    if check3 then linecommand := linecommand+' conditiontwo' end;
  end;
function check123()
  begin
    if check1 or check2 or check3 then
      begin
        linecommand='Executable file name.exe '+linecommand;
        Shellexec(linecommand);
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: What you're going to do ? What you've shown is valid; just better would be to return that command line from `FileParams` function instead of using a shared `linecommand` variable.

Comment: Originally I had five different lines in the Install Run section each one with different parameters.  I thought that for readability it would be better to build the parameter line.  In the Inno help files I can not find anything on FileParams.  Is there a separate function or is this the parameter statement in the files and install run sections.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`{code:...}` constant](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm) to insert a value calculated in a `[Code]` function into a specific value within a standard entry that accepts both strings and constants (such as the `Parameters` value of a `[Run]` entry).

Or you can write multiple entries and use a [`Check` function](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm) to determine which (if any) of them actually get executed.

Comment: I was trying not to use the component page but show a custom component page. For anyone else that is looking for a solution similar you can use the WizardFormComponents List to check and uncheck components. Use WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[0] with the index of your component item. You can then check and uncheck items on the component page and not have to show the component page. Just remember to handle the back button (clear your selections if you go back).

Comment: I don't see how that comment is in any way related to your question or my answer.

Comment: What I had been trying to do is build a variable string to use in the parameter line of the Install Run as I did not want to show the component selection screen.  From your comment I was able to find the WizardFormComponents List (although I am not sure how).  I probably should have commented better but as I am a newbie and it took me quite a while to find this I thought I would leave the comment for anyone who was looking for the same thing.  Sorry if I categorized this in the wrong place.  Thanks for the help.